# Unable to get current_location with facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with Facebook Api (PHP).
Why a cannot get current_location ( i need latitude longitude) of an authorized users?
Can someone help my to understand this permissions problem?

```
$q = $my->query("SELECT id_facebook FROM Utenti");
while ($obj=$q->fetch_object())
{
    $query = 'SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid = '.$obj->id_facebook;
    $response = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $query));
    echo "<pre>\n";
    var_dump($facebook->api("/".$obj->id_facebook."/permissions"));
    var_dump($facebook->api("/".$obj->id_facebook."?fields=location"));
    var_dump($response);
    echo "</pre><br>\n";
}
```

Permissions are:

```
array(2) {
    ["data"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>
                array(16) {
                    ["installed"]=> int(1)
                    ["basic_info"]=>int(1)
                    ["public_profile"]=>int(1)
                    ["create_note"]=>int(1)
                    ["photo_upload"]=>int(1)
                    ["publish_actions"]=>int(1)
                    ["publish_checkins"]=>int(1)
                    ["publish_stream"]=>int(1)
                    ["status_update"]=>int(1)
                    ["share_item"]=>int(1)
                    ["video_upload"]=>int(1)
                    ["user_birthday"]=>int(1)
                    ["user_hometown"]=>int(1)
                    ["user_location"]=>int(1)
                    ["user_friends"]=>int(1)
                    ["bookmarked"]=>int(1)
                }
        }
}
```

Example of $respone:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
        array(1) {
            ["current_location"]=>NULL
       }
}
```

Comment: And what result are you getting with `var_dump($facebook->api("/".$obj->id_facebook."?fields=location"));`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: Not every user has entered a current city in his profile. Are you sure that the respective user has set this?

Otherwise your code looks fine to me.